# Want to redirect the server url to server/somestring through nginx

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

want to redirect the server url to server url/somestring through nginx.conf.
Tried location /somestring{}  inside server tag in nginx.conf, didn't work. 
Please suggest how can i achieve that.

Comment: tried                location /test{
                   # rewrite clm-pun-td1wga.bmc.com/test http://rancher_servers_http;
                   # proxy_pass http://rancher_servers_http;
                  # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
               }
tried all above approaches, it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

An example of nginx config that allows to redirect multiple domains.
You can use a similar approach to redirect paths as well.

```
map $http_host $redirect_destination {
    hostnames;
    default where-to-go-by-default;
    my-domain where-to-redirect-my-domain;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$redirect_destination/some-path;
    }
}
```